# Correct terminology and examples for nesting/routing views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been doing ASP.NET for a while, and have done very little in MVC (in general), but very new at the ASP.NET MVC framework, as well as the correct terminology on a few things.

Here is my example (actual application I am working on is different, but this is a public example I can use) - I want to create a simpler version of [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), but in .net.

I want to list issues, in such a way that if I go to example.org/issues, I see a list of all issues (similar to http://www.redmine.org/issues), across all projects.

But if I go to the project, as in example.org/project/issues, I see just the issues for that project (similar to http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues). This would be the same for example.org/project2/issues, etc.

What is the correct term for this? I would assume that the developers didn't rewrite the 'issues' code in two places, that they reused this code.

Since I don't know the fully correct term for this, it is hard to find good examples in the ASP.NET MVC world that I can start with. So the second part of this, is what would be an example that I could look at in ASP.NET MVC, and how should this look in Visual Studio to me?

There would also be several other things under /project/, like settings, details, logs, etc, similar on how one would navigate http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/.

Finally, what if projects was not on the top level? As in, what if my application was more like:

```
example.org/
example.org/projects/
example.org/projects/project1
example.org/projects/project1/issues
example.org/projects/project2
example.org/dashboard/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up one controller called whatever you'd like (I'll use RedMineController).

In that controller you'll have a single action method named ListIssues. Accept a parameter named ProjectName:

```
public ActionResult ListIssues(string projectName) {}
```

Lastly create two routes in your global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Issues Root",
    "issues",
    new { controller = "RedMine", action = "ListIssues" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Project Issues",
    "projects/{projectName}/issues",
    new { controller = "RedMine", action = "ListIssues" }
);
```

In your ListIssues action, check if projectName == null, and if so get all issues, otherwise get specific ones. The first route will pass null, the second will pass what is in the URL. Don't forget to throw a 404 if the project name in the URL is invalid.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Removed previous comments since I cleared a lot of this up. First I noticed these routes need to before the default. Secondly, I made a listissues view, that I assume would be where they all lead too. Is there a way I can then reuse this code, say for a project page to show the last 10 issues?

Comment: If you call routes.MapRoute and the second parameter is "issues" but you get a 404, something is wrong. Maybe the project has not been re-built since the change?If you mapped the route to the wrong controller I'd expect to see some type of detailed error message, but not a 404.

Comment: yeah, it was because of my routing. Im going to move the sub list part in my comment to another question.

Answer (score 0):

well though not a proper ans. but you can do what you want easily by just reversing the way you are doing them.. ie
instead of doing `www.example.org/project/issues` do `www.example.org/issues/project`or just `www.example.org/issues`
this way you can easily make a `issues` controller and everything in the url after `issues` can be this string by which you would be able to determine the resource for which you need to list all the issues. an example route for it can be

```
"{issues}/{*resource}",new{controller="issues"}
```